# Count first occurences of a value in a column of lists based on another column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with a column of lists ('value') and a column with the count of items in the respective list ('no_of_values') sorted descendingly by the no_of_values.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[['AB','BC','CD','DE','EF','FG','GH','HI'],
                          ['BC','CD','DE','IJ','JK','KL','LM'],
                          ['AB','CD','DE','IJ','JK','GH','HI'],
                          ['AB','CD','DE','MN'],
                          ['C', 'D', 'M'],
                          ['MN','NO'],
                          ['APQ']],
                 'no_of_values': [8,7,7,4,3,2,1]})
```

Now I want to count how many items in the value lists, going from the highest no_of_values to the lowest.

I tried:

```
df['no_of_1st_occurence'] = (~df['value'].explode().duplicated()).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Which results in:

```
    value                     no_of_values  no_of_1st_occurence
0   [AB, BC, CD, DE, EF, FG, GH, HI]    8   8
1   [BC, CD, DE, IJ, JK, KL, LM]        7   4
2   [AB, CD, DE, IJ, JK, GH, HI]        7   0
3   [AB, CD, DE, MN]                    4   1
4   [C, D, M]                           3   3
5   [MN, NO]                            2   1
6   [APQ]                               1   1
```

But this does not work, when a no_of_values occurs for more than one time (here: "7"). I would like to split the count of 1st_occurences in that case into strict no_of_1st_occurence (if an item in the value list did not occur for a higher no_of_values nor the same no_of_values) and shared_1st_occurences (if an item in the value list did not occur for a higher no_of_values, but occurs atleast another times for the same no_of_values).

The desired outcome would be:

```
    value                     no_of_values | strict_1st_occurence | shared_1st_occurence
0   [AB, BC, CD, DE, EF, FG, GH, HI]    8        8                  0
1   [BC, CD, DE, IJ, JK, KL, LM]        7        2                  2
2   [AB, CD, DE, IJ, JK, GH, HI]        7        0                  2
3   [AB, CD, DE, MN]                    4        1                  0
4   [C, D, M]                           3        3                  0
5   [MN, NO]                            2        1                  0
6   [APQ]                               1        1                  0
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the desired outcome - can you share your current outcome, and a snippet of the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably way too complicated, but I got it working and came to the desired outcome:

```
def remove_duplicates_from_list(x):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(x))

def get_duplicates_from_list(L):
    seen = set()
    seen2 = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    seen2_add = seen2.add
    for item in L:
        if item in seen:
            seen2_add(item)
        else:
            seen_add(item)
    return list(seen2)

def get_intersection_from_two_lists(x,y):
    return list(set(x).intersection(y))

    
import itertools
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[['AB','BC','CD','DE','EF','FG','GH','HI'],
                          ['BC','CD','DE','IJ','JK','KL','LM'],
                          ['AB','CD','DE','IJ','JK','GH','HI'],
                          ['AB','CD','DE','MN'],
                          ['C', 'D', 'M'],
                          ['MN','NO'],
                          ['APQ']],
                 'no_of_values': [8,7,7,4,3,2,1]})

list_of_unique_no_of_values=[]

for value_no in df.no_of_values:
    if value_no not in list_of_unique_no_of_values:
        list_of_unique_no_of_values.append(value_no)

df['values_of_same_no_of_values'] = ""
df['new_value'] = ""

value_list=[]
        
for unique_value_no in list_of_unique_no_of_values:
    mask=(df['no_of_values']==unique_value_no)
    for k in df.loc[mask,'value']:
        for i in k:
            df.loc[mask,'values_of_same_no_of_values']=df.loc[mask,'values_of_same_no_of_values']+i+","
            if i not in value_list:
                value_list.append(i)
                df.loc[mask,'new_value']=df.loc[mask,'new_value']+i+","
df['values_of_same_no_of_values'] = df['values_of_same_no_of_values'].str[:-1]
df['values_of_same_no_of_values'] = df['values_of_same_no_of_values'].str.split(',')
df['values_of_same_no_of_values'] = df['values_of_same_no_of_values'].apply (lambda row: remove_duplicates_from_list(row))


df['new_value'] = df['new_value'].str[:-1]
df['new_value'] = df['new_value'].str.split(',')
df['new_value'] = df['new_value'].apply (lambda row: remove_duplicates_from_list(row))    

df['intersection_value_new_value'] = [list(set(a).intersection(b)) for a, b in zip(df.value, df.new_value)]
df['len_intersection_value_new_value'] = df['intersection_value_new_value'].str.len()

list_of_all_intersection_values=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df['intersection_value_new_value'].tolist()))
shared_1st_occurence_values=get_duplicates_from_list(list_of_all_intersection_values)

df['shared_1st_occurence_values'] = df['intersection_value_new_value'].apply (lambda row: get_intersection_from_two_lists(row, shared_1st_occurence_values))
df['strict_1st_occurence_values'] = (df['intersection_value_new_value'].map(set) - df['shared_1st_occurence_values'].map(set)).map(list)


df['shared_1st_occurence'] = df['shared_1st_occurence_values'].str.len()
df['strict_1st_occurence'] = df['len_intersection_value_new_value']-df['shared_1st_occurence']

df = df[['value','no_of_values','strict_1st_occurence','shared_1st_occurence']]

df
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting the first occurences of items from higher number of values to lowest returns the foollowing

```
nombre_first_occurences=[]
list_first_occurences=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
  
  list_bet=[]
  if i==0:
    nombre_first_occurences.append(len(df.value.iloc[i]))
    list_first_occurences.append(df.value.iloc[0])
  else:
    for k in df.value.iloc[i]:
        if k not in [j for h in list_first_occurences for j in h]and k not in list_bet:
          
          
          list_bet.append(k)
    list_first_occurences.append(list_bet)
    nombre_first_occurences.append(len(list_bet))

df['list_first_occurences']=list_first_occurences
df['nombre_first_occurences']=nombre_first_occurences
df
```

[image: results]

Comment: Thank you, but your code does exactly the same as the oneliner:
`df['no_of_1st_occurence'] = (~df['value'].explode().duplicated()).groupby(level=0).sum()`

Comment: oh yess that's true, can you explain the use of the tilde ~